# PostGIS and JPA 2.0

Tags: java, geospatial, jpa-2.0, postgis

I'd like to map datatypes from PostGIS with JPA 2.0. I googled for solutions or examples, but all I can find is that JPA does not support mapping of custom data types. Is it still like this in JPA 2.0? Has anybody a hint for an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I googled for solutions or examples, but all I can find is, that JPA does not support mapping of custom data types. Is it still in JPA 2.0?

Yes. So you'll have to rely on specific extensions. For Hibernate, the [Hibernate Spatial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/) project provides ready to use spatial dialects and custom types:

> Hibernate Spatial is a generic
>   extension to Hibernate for handling
>   geographic data. Hibernate Spatial is
>   open source and licensed, like
>   Hibernate, under the LGPL license.
>
> Hibernate Spatial allows you to deal
>   with geographic data in a standardized
>   way. It abstracts away from the
>   specific way your database supports
>   geographic data, and provides a
>   standardized, cross-database interface
>   to geographic data storage and query
>   functions.
>
> Hibernate Spatial supports most of the
>   functions of the OGC Simple Feature
>   Specification. Supported databases
>   are: Oracle 10g/11g,
>   Postgresql/Postgis, Microsoft SQL
>   Server and MySQL.

Comment: Too bad it even still does not support Geography type of postgis, only geometry type =/

Answer (score 1):

DataNucleus supports JPA1+2 and also has a Spatial plugin supporting PostGIS amongst other things

Comment: Correct. JPA defines persistence of very basic Java types, not extensions

Answer (score 1):

I just did this with Hibernate Spatial.  They have a great tutorial on their website even though I assume you have found an answer from now.