# What database and java library to use for Spatial Analysis?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0, postgis

I have been working on a web project that stores locations for users. The project uses currently MySql 5.5 and JPA 2 for mapping the relation database, together with EJB 3.1 as the middle tier. I store longitude and latitude data in Decimal data types in MySql.

I want to expand the project so the user can search for Points (GPS coordinates) near the location he/she marks out (through using Google Map API 3) on the map.

I need some hints and suggestions before starting transforming or changing components in my project. If possible with tutorial and how to achieve the changes and what tools (library, dev tools, etc.) to use. Here are my questions.

1. Can I use the Spatial extension in MySql (using data types like Point) and map this to entities that are supported by JPA 2 (like DataNucleus library, if they are supported by JPA 2). That are light weight and can persist them self through the persistent layer.
2. Is it better to move to PostGIS and Postgres (which seem to have better spatial support) with all the pain and effort needed to change database and using hibernate instead. Netbeans has Hibernate support but when trying with the JDBC for PostGis I stumble upon problems. Need a good tutorial to follow to get started if I go down this road.
3. Using the infrastructure that is already in-place and compute the distance from lactation A and B. Similar to the way done in this article by [Jan Philip Matuschek](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates)

Excuse me for clustering the questions. 
Regards Chris

Comment: I've immersed myself a bit more. What I do know by now, is that I am not only in need of spatial analysis. But I need a DB that has Geographic support and I am less interested in pure cartesian calculations. Since the positions I'll collect will be on larger, regional scale. PostGIS support WGS 84, there are not many functions. But it has the once I need for now. I'll report back when I have a working prototype.

Comment: I haven't found anything yet if MySQL support Geographic (geodetic) coordinates.

Comment: I'm not aware of MySQL's support for geography, but this is all possible in PostGIS.   PostGIS has a 'GISTree' index that allows you to index your geography (r-tree in Oracle) which allows for much faster geo queries.Are you planning on doing 'regions' (you can define a polygon using lat/lons and then search for which DB points are in that polygon for example), or are you planning on doing 'closest to' or 'within 2 miles of this point'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL's Spacial extension is usually OK if you only have point locations, but it starts to get overwhelmed if you want to find points in polygons (i.e., query by region), or use fancy indices and search algorithms. There is a [really good cross comparison](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare) to help show the differences between the different spatial DBs.

I'd see that there are many more benefits to migrating to PostgreSQL and PostGIS. There are also many more GIS applications that work naively with PostGIS, such as QGIS, Geoserver, etc. The most recent version of PostGIS has [a KNN nearest neighbor search operator](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/geometry_distance_centroid.html) to quickly find, for example, the nearest 25 points out of several million rows to a particular point on your map (see also [here](http://blog.opengeo.org/2011/09/28/indexed-nearest-neighbour-search-in-postgis/)).

See [the manual](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch06.html#id2821588) for JDBC and PostGIS. As for JPA, see [PostGIS and JPA 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387170/postgis-and-jpa-2-0)

As for distance calculations, see [ST_Distance](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) and [ST_Distance_Spheroid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html).

Comment: I don't know much about PostGIS but a comparison that talks about PostgreSQL 8.3 is more than outdated.

Comment: A comparison refresh is certainly due, especially now that PostGIS 2.0 is out. Much of the table is still valid. Notable additions are that PostGIS now has a `geography` type (as of version 1.5) for "True Geodetic support".

Comment: Yes, I figured that a move to postGIS 2 is one good way to go. Since I will search location in and around several countries, so just plain cartesian calc is not enough. But I thinking of mongoDB, cause it seems easy to get working with plain Java objects (POJO). Has anyone tried geographic search (geodetic) for locations in mongoDB ?

Comment: It looks like there is [geospatial indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) support in MongoDB, but I don't have any first-hand experience with it. The "Spherical Model" looks like an OK approximation for linear distances using lat/long. It looks like it only uses MBR searches, so you can't reliably do detailed point-in-polygon queries.