# How to store geometry Point in Postgis database using java

Tags: java, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to store a geometry object into my postgist database, which has a table with a geometry column. I got the geometry value from another table with a geometry column, and I print the value I got previously and it's ok. To store geometry value I use next function:

```
static void insertaGeometria( Geometry geom, int idInstalacion) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

        Connection congeom = conectarPGA();

        String geomsql ="INSERT INTO georrepositorio.geometria(id, point) VALUES (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement psSE= congeom.prepareStatement(geomsql);
        psSE.setInt(1, idInstalacion);
        psSE.setObject(2, geom);    

        psSE.execute();
        psSE.close();   
        congeom.close();    
    }
```

But I always get this error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for
>   an instance of org.postgis.Point. Use setObject() with an explicit
>   Types value to specify the type to use.

Do anyone know how to store it? ='(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[See the manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ch06.html#id408924) for the Java client. From this I see two ideas. Try using `PGgeometry` instead of `Geometry` types for `geom`. Then, add the geometry type to the connection `congeom`:

```
((org.postgresql.PGConnection)congeom).addDataType("geometry",Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
```

Comment: what to do in case of jpa

Comment: @bob-cac not sure (I don't use JPA); see [if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2387170/327026)

Answer (score 3):

To my experience I have managed to add point using such expression (note the Point which the request is iterated by is my own class):

```
    java.sql.Connection conpg;

    try {
/*
* Load the JDBC driver and establish a connection.
*/

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis_22_sample";
        conpg = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "postgres", "nypassw");
/*
* Add the geometry types to the connection. Note that you
* must cast the connection to the pgsql-specific connection
* implementation before calling the addDataType() method.
*/
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) conpg).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
        //((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conpg).addDataType("point",Class.forName("org.postgis.Point"));
/*
* Create a statement and execute a select query.
*/
        conpg.setAutoCommit(false);

        for (Point p : points) {

            org.postgis.Point pointToAdd = new org.postgis.Point();
            pointToAdd.setX(p.getLongitude());
            pointToAdd.setY(p.getLatitude());

            //Statement s = conn.createStatement();
            //String geomsql = ;
            PreparedStatement psSE = conpg.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO public.\"poi-point\" (name,geom,leisure) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            psSE.setString(1, p.getDescription());
            psSE.setObject(2, new org.postgis.PGgeometry(pointToAdd));
            psSE.setString(3, "marina");

            psSE.execute();
            //ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("select geom,id from geomtable");
            //while (r.next()) {
  /*
  * Retrieve the geometry as an object then cast it to the geometry type.
  * Print things out.
  */
            //    PGgeometry geom = (PGgeometry) r.getObject(1);
            //    int id = r.getInt(2);
            //    System.out.println("Row " + id + ":");
            //    System.out.println(geom.toString());
            //}
            //s.close();
        }
        conpg.commit();
        conpg.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

maven dependencies to make it working are

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.postgis</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgis-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- NOTE: Version 4.2 has bundled slf4j -->
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- NOTE: Version 4.2 has bundled slf4j -->
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- NOTE: Version 4.2 has bundled slf4j -->
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
```

Note, that you not nessesarilly need to exclude the dependencies (it was needed for my own compatiblity)